# Showing uniform convergence of a sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2x\over n^2-x^2}$ is uniformly convergent on a finite closed interval not containing the integers.
By the comparison test I know that the series converges.

Then taking $\lim_{n\to \infty}{2x\over n^2-x^2}$ we have that $\lim = 0$

Now there exists some $ \epsilon>0$ s.t. for $N$ large enough we have $\left|{2x\over n^2-x^2}\right|<\epsilon$

I tried to isolate it so that ${1\over\epsilon}<{n^2-x^2\over2x} = {n^2\over2x} - {x\over2}< {n^2\over2x}$

However now I obtain that:
$(\frac{2x}{\epsilon})^{1\over2}<n$

clearly, $n$ is dependent on $x$ so this cannot be uniformly convergent?

Comment: "on a finite closed interval not containing the integers" should be "on a finite closed interval not containing **any** integers"

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to show that $\frac{2x}{n^2-x^2}$ is bounded for each $n$, you could argue then with epsilons over the supremum of the image.